# MYSQL multiple Triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a MYSQL table and two of the fields are called Rate_per_unit and Cost. First I want the field Rate_per_unit to populate itself from another table called SHD_TEACHER then I want the field COST to populate itself also from RATE in SHD_TEACHER and multiplies by UNITS.

I have the following code which is giving me an error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER RATE_PER_UNIT_1
BEFORE INSERT ON SHD_SCHEDULE
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.RATE_PER_UNIT = 
  (
    SELECT RATE 
      FROM SHD_TEACHER
     WHERE TEACHERID = NEW.TEACHER_ID
     LIMIT 1
  )

SET NEW.COST = (
    SELECT RATE 
      FROM SHD_TEACHER
     WHERE TEACHERID = NEW.TEACHER_ID

  ) * UNITS
```

Any help please?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using your syntax, I would expect a `delimiter` statement and a `begin`/`end` block.  So, try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER RATE_PER_UNIT_1
BEFORE INSERT ON SHD_SCHEDULE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.RATE_PER_UNIT = 
  (
    SELECT RATE 
      FROM SHD_TEACHER t
     WHERE t.TEACHERID = NEW.TEACHER_ID
     LIMIT 1
  )

  SET NEW.COST = (
    SELECT t.RATE 
      FROM SHD_TEACHER t
     WHERE t.TEACHERID = NEW.TEACHER_ID

  ) * NEW.UNITS
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

You have a `limit 1` in the  first subquery, suggesting that there might be multiple matches.  If so, you will get a run-time error in the second.  Also, `UNITS` is just hanging out there, all alone.  I assumed it is in the `NEW` record.

Here is another way to write this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER RATE_PER_UNIT_1
BEFORE INSERT ON SHD_SCHEDULE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT NEW.RATE_PER_UNIT := t.RATE, NEW.COST := t.RATE * NEW.UNITS
    FROM (SELECT t.*
          FROM SHD_TEACHER t
          WHERE t.TEACHERID = NEW.TEACHER_ID
          LIMIT 1
         ) t
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: many thanks but in both your examples I am getting an error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

Comment: OK solved thanks to @Gordon Linoff. Here is the code:DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER RATE_PER_UNIT_2
BEFORE INSERT ON SHD_SCHEDULE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.RATE_PER_UNIT = 
  (
    SELECT RATE 
      FROM SHD_TEACHER t
     WHERE t.TEACHERID = NEW.TEACHER_ID
     LIMIT 1
  );

  SET NEW.COST = 
(
    SELECT t.RATE 
      FROM SHD_TEACHER t
     WHERE t.TEACHERID = NEW.TEACHER_ID

  ) * NEW.UNITS
;
end